# How do we index a tensor in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to understand the following code.

```
content_array[:, :, :, 0] -= 103.939
content_array[:, :, :, 1] -= 116.779
content_array[:, :, :, 2] -= 123.68
content_array = content_array[:, :, :, ::-1]

style_array[:, :, :, 0] -= 103.939
style_array[:, :, :, 1] -= 116.779
style_array[:, :, :, 2] -= 123.68
style_array = style_array[:, :, :, ::-1]
```

`content_array` and `style_array` are arrays with dimensions of 
`(1, 512, 512, 3)` respectively.

What i don't really understand is the indexing(`[:, :, :, 0]`, `[:, :, :, 1]`, `[:, :, :, 2]`). Does this means we are indexing each dimension? and why do we use ':'?

Comment: Which library are you using? numpy? pandas? tensorflow? What are the types of `content_array` and `style_array` (`np.array` / `tf.Tensor` etc)?

Comment: I am using numpy and keras with tensorflow backend. And it's `np.asarray' and 'np.expand_dims`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of numpy's most interesting indexing features, is the ability to index slices. Slices are subarrays in a given dimensions, they are written in the form of `i:j:k` where i is the starting index, j the ending (not included), and k the step. Specifying all 3 parameters would be tedious most of the time, that's why they all have default values. i=0, j=n where n is the length of the array, k=1. Therefore selecting all the elements along a dimension would come down to writting `array[::]` for which a syntactic sugar is `array[:]`.

Therefore `content_array[:, :, :, 0]` is an array of dimension `(1, 512, 512)`. And writing `content_array[:, :, :, 0] -= 103.939` means set all the values of the array taken by selecting all the elements such that they have index 0 on last dimension, and decrement all these elements by 103.939.

I would recommend that you read https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html.